# Openlayers 3: Continue drawing the initial Line, after drawend triggered with double click

Tags: draw, openlayers

Is it possible to continue drawing from the last point of LineString after 'drawend' is raised from double click? EVERY example I found online starts another draw from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine a Draw interaction with a Modify interaction. That still won't allow you to continue drawing the first line, but it will at least allow you to modify existing and add new vertices to the drawn line.

But if you also add a Snap interaction to the mix, you can continue where you left, although a new LineString will be started. All you need to do afterwards is concatenate the drawn LineStrings to a single one, or create a MultiLineString from all LineStrings. You can test this with the http://openlayers.org/en/v4.3.1/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html example.

Comment: Ok let's say I go with the first option (Modify). Can you expand a bit more?
How can I append vertices in initial LineString? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Is it not possible to achieve such functionality without using modify? Makes sense since I want to "extend" previous drawing. What I want is instead of resetting and restart from Vertex 1, keep initial and append vertex n + 1 (and corresponding edge).

Answer (score 0):

After struggling two days with this issue, here's what I made using [JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) library ([example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/jsts.html?q=jsts) of the library integration on OL3):

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource
        })
    ],
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([126.979293, 37.528787]),
        zoom: 15
    })
});

var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: vectorSource,
    type: 'MultiLineString'
});

var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({source: vectorSource});
var snap = new ol.interaction.Snap({source: vectorSource});
var select = new ol.interaction.Select({source: vectorSource});
map.addInteraction(draw);
map.addInteraction(modify);
map.addInteraction(snap);

var ol3Parser = new jsts.io.ol3Parser();

//listen to drawend
draw.on('drawend', function (evt) {
    mergeLineString(evt.feature);
});

//listen to modifyend
modify.on('modifyend', function (evt) {
    mergeLineString(evt.features.getArray()[0]);
});

function mergeLineString(currentFeature){
    var features: vectorSource.getFeatures();
    var feature, currentGeo, featureGeo, union, i;
    // loop forward because we have to remove the merged features
    for (i = features.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        feature = features[i];
        // convert data with JSTS
        currentGeo = ol3Parser.read(currentFeature.getGeometry());
        featureGeo = ol3Parser.read(feature.getGeometry());
        // check intersection with another feature already on the vector
        if (currentGeo.intersects(featureGeo)) {
            // create union
            union = currentGeo.union(featureGeo);
            // set the new geometry to the last feature added
            currentFeature.setGeometry(ol3Parser.write(union));
            // remove the feature which was merged
            vectorSource.removeFeature(feature);
        }
    }
}
```

Any improvements of this code is really welcome if needed, because I'm quite new with OL3 - and I need this functionnality a lot!

**/!\ Warning:** With this code, do NOT use draw and modify at the same time as ahocevar suggested - or you won't be able to continue drawing from an existant linestring (the click won't listen). You have to bind two differents actions : draw + snap on a drawing button, then modify + snap on an edit button.